How to retrieve the name of the virus that was found with clamd, with the clamav_client crate?
When using clamav_client, how does one retrieve the name of the virus that was found by clamd ?
let buffer = br#"X5O!P%@AP[4\PZX54(P^)7CC)7}$EICAR-STANDARD-ANTIVIRUS-TEST-FILE!$H+H*"#;
let scan_buffer_response = clamav_client::scan_buffer(buffer, clamd_tcp, None).unwrap();
let data_clean = clamav_client::clean(&scan_buffer_response).unwrap();
if ! data_clean {
    println!("The data is infected!");  // but with which virus ?
}


str::from_utf8(&scan_buffer_reponse).unwrap() will contain the full server response, including the virus name; the clamav_client::clean function just does that and then searches the string for OK or FOUND.

Thanks for pointing that out, and that it may help in the future to examine the source code of other libraries myself. Now all I need is some logic to reliably extract the name from the string and present it to the user.

I did briefly glance at the clam av server docs for a definitive specification regarding the response format, but nothing immediately jumped out at me.
